# multiple select with aggregates on the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have been trying to get this done with unions, joins on the same table and nested selects but I just cannot get the result I need.

So, to start: all the data I need is in *table1*, which short version structure is like this:

**ownerID** *varchar(25)*
**supervisorID** *varchar(25)*
**statusID** *int*
Sample data is:

```
john.smith | joe.blogs | 1
john.smith | joe.blogs | 1
john.smith | joe.blogs | 1
john.smith | joe.blogs | 2
jane.doe   | joe.blogs | 1
jane.doe   | joe.blogs | 1
jane.doe   | joe.blogs | 1
jane.doe   | joe.blogs | 1
billy.bob  | mary.jane | 1
billy.bob  | mary.jane | 2
```

What I wish to get, in a pseudo-sql would be:

```
SELECT ownerID, COUNT(*) as CountOne, COUNT(*) as CountTwo
FROM table1
WHERE supervisorID='joe.blogs'AND statusID=1
OR supervisorID='joe.blogs'AND statusID=2
GROUP BY ownerID
```

producing the below result:

```
  userID   | countOne | countTwo
----------------------------------
john.smith |     3    |    1
----------------------------------
jane.doe   |     4    |    0
```

obviously the pseudo-SQL has no right to work, but like I said I tried with UNION, JOIN on the same table, nested Selects, and ask google but nothing I produced would give me required result :(

The DB is using PostreSql.

Comment: _PostreSql_ or _PostgreSQL_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUM instead of COUNT and sum only values that are matching the statusId you need - for CountOne -> Status = 1 and for CountTwo -> Status = 2:

```
SELECT ownerId, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN statusId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN statusId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM    table1
WHERE   supervisorId = 'joe.blogs'
GROUP BY ownerId
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great! Never thought about using SUM's. I tried similar with COUNT instead of SUM but than the first count was correct but the second was a copy of first

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ownerID , 
sum(case when statusID =1 then 1 else 0 end) as countOne,
sum(case when statusID =2 then 1 else 0 end) as countTwo
from table1
group by ownerID
```